# What is a spanning set for subspace $\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> What is a spanning set for the subspace $\{0\}$?

Is the question trying to say that every spanning set can linearly combines to form zero subspace?

Comment: I don't know what it's trying to say, but there are exactly two spanning sets for $\{0\}$, namely the empty set $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$. The emppty set is a basis; the other is not.

Comment: @1412: It depends on the definition of "spanning set" that you're working with. Care to share?

Answer (score 1):

The spanning set of a set of vectors $\mathcal{V} = \{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\ldots,\vec{v}_n\}$ is defined as the set $\text{span}(\mathcal{V}) = \{ \vec{x} \mid \vec{x} = c_1\vec{v}_1 + \dots + c_n\vec{v}_n \}$. Take $\mathcal{V} = \{ \vec{0} \}$, then the spanning set is $\text{span}(\mathcal{V}) = \{ \vec{0} \}$.